# Map checked checkboxes to hidden field after element is clicked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, coffeescript, hidden-field

I have an element with the class of `.selectall`. When I click that element, all table rows are then `checked`. What I would like to do is take all the `data-id` values of the checked checkboxes and store them in a hidden field with the ID of `#selected_items`. At the moment I have the current coffeescript that allows me to select each checkbox individually and map the `data-id` to the hidden field value. So I need the ability to click the `.selectall` element, have the hidden field populate, and then reflect any changes if I decide to individually uncheck any of the checkboxes.

HTML

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn selectall" type="button">Select All</button>
    <button class="btn unselectall" type="button">Unselect All</button>
</div>

<table class="coupons">
    <input class="inline" data-id="1" type="checkbox">
    <input class="inline" data-id="2" type="checkbox">
    <input class="inline" data-id="3" type="checkbox">
    ...
</table>

<input id="selected_items" name="selected_items" type="hidden" value="">
```

Coffeescript

```
$('.coupons input[type="checkbox"]').change(->
    ids = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
        .map(-> $(this).data("id"))
        .get().join(",")

    $("#selected_items").val(ids)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
update = () -> 
    ids = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
        .map(-> $(this).data("id"))
        .get().join(",")

    $("#selected_items").val(ids)

$('.coupons input[type="checkbox"]').change(update)
$('.selectall').click(->
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
    update()
)
$('.unselectall').click(->
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
    update()
)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y9qJS/) - minor markup changes for easy debugging